# Enum as generic type inside a class but using methods require an explicit cast

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am using enums as generic type parameters for my class. The problem is that I am not able to use its methods without an explicit cast (this must be due to the runtime type erasure).
Consider the following:

```
public enum TaskDetail {
    CAR_WASH(100, 2);

    private int serviceFees;
    //Something else.
    public int getServiceFees() {
        return serviceFees;
    }
}
```

I am using this as type in class as:

```
public class Task<E extends Enum<TaskDetail>> implements Runnable {
    private E taskDetail;

    public Task(E taskDetail) {
        this.setTaskDetail(taskDetail);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something with taskDetail:
        //not able to access methods without explicit cast. 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task<TaskDetail> t = new Task<TaskDetail>(TaskDetail.CAR_PAINT);
        t.taskDetail.getServiceFees(); //This is fine.
    }
}
```

Why I am not able to do this? I am probably mistaking something as with normal class type parameters this is possible.

Comment: why do you define Task as `Task<E extends Enum<TaskDetail>>`?

Comment: @wero I want to create different types of tasks based on type so as to use information contained in TaskDetail (like task time and duration).

Comment: @abksrv: it sounds like you're mixing up types and enum constants.  You can't create a `Task<TaskDetail.CAR_WASH>`; you can't parameterize types based on non-types, and `CAR_WASH` is not a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need generic type in Task class, this is just fine

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private TaskDetail taskDetail;

    public Task(TaskDetail taskDetail) {
        this.setTaskDetail(taskDetail);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task t = new Task(TaskDetail.CAR_WASH);
        t.taskDetail.getServiceFees(); //This is fine.
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it. But is there a way Enums might be used as Type params?

Comment: @abksrv check Enum#valueOf method, it has generic type. I guess someone could write similar method - when you dynamically choose what enum type you should return.